# What is the node hardware requirements and kubernetes nginx ingress configuration required processing large files (3gb) in AKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

We have a requirement to process collection of files up to the limit of 3gb size in total via .net core api pods hosted in AKS cluster.

The 3 nodes cluster has the current node configuration as 16gb Ram and 2vCpus. I have also added some ingress annotations as below:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 5000M
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 5000M
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 5000M
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '14400'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: '14400'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '14400'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '14400'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: keepalive_timeout 3600s; client_body_timeout 3600s;
```

These changes helped to handle up to 2gb file sizes, by ingress utilizing 1.02cpu and 1000mi memory for almost 5 minutes.  The latest resource requirement I've updated for ingress is as below, but it didn't help either.

```
resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 1400m
      memory: 3000Mi
```

But struggling to process sizes more than 2gb and gets terminated after processing around 7 minutes and throwing an internal server error.

I couldn't find the exact log message yet and any suggestions on configuring azure metrics, logs, alerts is also helpful in addition to hardware and ingress configuration to handle 3gb file sizes successfully.

Comment: When you say it's struggling to process file sizes more than 2GB, do you mean 2GB files that are uploaded or 2GB files that nginx is returning or something else?  Also, is the internal server error thrown by nginx?  if so what error do you see?

Comment: Collection of 2GB files are uploaded successfully.  Yes, nginx is throwing an error I presume as no logs in our apis yet.  I will look into the logs in detail and provide some info when I can.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

For uploads of that size either publish the service port directly, or if the ingress provides some other functionality, disable request buffering in nginx.

Put the upload service on it's own ingress host: `upload.x.com`

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: off
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 3G
```

Failing that, buffer requests to temporary files so nginx isn't keeping the requests in memory.

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    client_body_in_file_only: on
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: 3G
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 64k
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 3G
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, while I've tried with buffering off for ngnix - getting timeout issues but the timeouts are set well ahead.  However configuring requests and limits are helping to process successfully, while it impacts the other PODs running in the same cluster though :(  Unfortunately this functionality is part of the existing service, which is responsible for more tasks, we could not get this service hosted as either as a loadbalancer or skip nginx at this moment.  Thanks